# Studies on how art affects people

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion

Are there more specific studies on how and why art affects people?

I think art is very subjective. I would like an answer that can encompass, if possible, both music, games and paintings when it comes to "art". I think the feeling reveals itself directly depending on the lifestyle. The educational system and work environment are almost entirely geared towards the development of the left hemisphere of the brain.